# What does a chi-square value of zero means in CFA?

Tags: structural-equation-modeling, amos

I am new to SEM and I am trying to run CFA for a 3-item Job satisfaction scale in Amos. I am getting the following as results.

```
Chi-square = .000
Degrees of freedom = 0
Probability level cannot be computed
```

I am not able to understand what does this mean.
Please help me understand how do I interpret this.

Here is the model:

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your model is saturated. You have 6 covariance moments (three variances and three covariances), and you are estimating 6 parameters (factor variance, two loadings, three measurement error/unique variances). The problem has an exact solution, and zero objective function means that Amos successfully found that solution.

It also means that you cannot use the overall goodness of fit test to see how well your model fits. There is simply no further information to extract from your covariance matrix.

Comment: thanks StasK. One additional question. I have to report CFA for this scale. How do I do that in this case?

Comment: Just say that the model is saturated, and goodness of fit tests are not available/not applicable.